# jQuery .resize() doesn't work properly on Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, resize

I'm trying to create a scroller plugin with jQuery. I need to catch the container elements resizing events to set the scroll position for new size. But I'm stuck on this issue: `.resize()` doesn't work on Chrome for any element but window.

Is there any way to catch resizing events with jQuery or JavaScript? I've also tried setting `onresize` attribute but it fires for once. I added the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJMYd/100/) link below.

Comment: Does it work correctly in any browser?

Comment: It works on IE8. I'm shocked about that :) I did't test on ff. And chrome doesnt run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onresize):

> Only the `window` object has an onresize event.

The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) also only mention `window`.

Perhaps you could benefit from the [jQuery resize event plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) which seems to do exactly what you need.

**EDIT:** Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJMYd/103/) that includes the plugin. The code is identical, but it works as you expect because it includes the plugin (see the "Add Resources" tab in the fiddle).

Comment: Thanks, i see that it uses setTimer function to define a timer. May that way causes low memory if i use it too many times on a page?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to catch resize anywhere else but window?

If it's because you need to watch DOM elements reducing the size of your div, just trigger yourself the resize event.

```
$(window).trigger('resize')
```

Comment: Thansk, it's useful if i know when the size of element changes. But it's like a trick more than i solution :)

Comment: In my case it was because I had an absolute positioned div with dynamic content, which height had to affect min-height ot it's parent.